# why .htaccess is calling same page for every request and how can I modify it?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using following .htaccess rules on my website.

Using this I am hiding php extension and creating seo based url.

now when I access a page like

```
http://localhost/freelancer/happiechef/login or   
http://localhost/freelancer/happiechef/sign
```

It's calling city.php page but I used city.php page when I request this url

```
http://localhost/freelancer/happiechef/california
```

Something is wrong in my .htaccess rules.

**3 type of url i want :**

1) http://localhost/freelancer/happiechef/california = will be called city.php?city=$value

2) http://localhost/freelancer/happiechef/california/2/an-exploration-of-ramen = will be called menu-details.php?city=$value&mid=$value&title=$value

3) http://localhost/freelancer/happiechef/california/2/an-exploration-of-ramen = will be called booking.php page. So url will be : http://localhost/freelancer/happiechef/california/2/an-exploration-of-ramen/booking

**.htaccess file :**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /freelancer/happiechef/not-found.php
ErrorDocument 500 /freelancer/happiechef/not-found.php
RewriteEngine On        

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ city.php?city=$1    [NC,L] 
#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([\d]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ menu-details?mid=$2 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ menu-details.php?city=$1&mid=$2&title=$3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that .htaccess. Obviously we  can't do anything to help fix it, since you haven't SHOWN US what's in that file. And this is also not a code writing service. We're not going to bang out a .htaccess for you.

Comment: OOOH. Its my mistake. I have updated my question @MarcB

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located in your filesystem?

Comment: In  Root folder..

Comment: Where does `city.php` exist and is `/freelancer/happiechef/` a real directory?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `/freelancer/happiechef/` is a directory. Following code should work in `/freelancer/happiechef/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /freelancer/happiechef/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ menu-details.php?city=$1&mid=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ booking.php?city=$1&mid=$2&title=$3&action=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ city.php?city=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Well, this url is not working `http://localhost/freelancer/happiechef/california/2/an-exploration-of-ramen/booking` it will be called booking.php page and I need to get the mid

Comment: Yes, you should keep both `ErrorDocument` lines. Also tell what is internal (actual) `booking.php` URI. For ex. we have `menu-details.php?city=$1&mid=$2&title=$3`

Comment: I've added a new rule for `booking.php`. Take note of query parameters that you can modify as per your code.